# Difficulty laying out SWT Text Controls within a group

Tags: java, swt

I am having a problem getting SWT Text controls to lay out the way I want them to within a group.  Specifically, I'm having a difficult time getting the `verticalSpan` passed to the `GridData` to be reflected in the GUI asset.  In the example below, the 3 controls that I am unable to get to display correctly are `descriptionText`, `defaultActionText`, and `defaultReportActionText`, but `translationText` display displays correctly.  I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly here so I appreciate any feedback!

Group:

```
    paramsFieldComposite = new Group( upperRightComposite, SWT.BORDER );
    // TODO: Change group to composite and remove .setText()
    paramsFieldComposite.setText( "paramsFieldComposite" );
    paramsFieldComposite.setLayoutData( new GridData( SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1 ) );
    paramsFieldComposite.setLayout( new GridLayout( 2, true ) );
```

Translation Controls (working as I would expect with a width of 1 and height of 3):

```
    Label hostnameLabel = new Label( paramsFieldComposite, SWT.NONE );
    hostnameLabel.setLayoutData( new GridData( SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, false, false, 1, 1 ) );
    hostnameLabel.setText( configResourceBundle.geti18nDisplay( "HostnameLabel" ) );

    Label translationLabel = new Label( paramsFieldComposite, SWT.NONE );
    translationLabel.setLayoutData( new GridData( SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false, 1, 1 ) );
    translationLabel.setText( configResourceBundle.geti18nDisplay( "TranslationLabel" ) );

    hostnameText = new TextControl( paramsFieldComposite, SWT.BORDER );
    hostnameText.setLayoutData( new GridData( SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false, 1, 1 ) );
    hostnameText.setEditable( true );

    translationText = new TextControl( paramsFieldComposite, SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.WRAP );
    translationText.setLayoutData( new GridData( SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false, 1, 3 ) );
    translationText.setEditable( true );
```

Description/Action Controls (not working as I'm expecting, I want them to all have a height of 3 instead of 1):

```
    Label descriptionLabel = new Label( paramsFieldComposite, SWT.NONE );
    descriptionLabel.setLayoutData( new GridData( SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false, 2, 1 ) );
    descriptionLabel.setText( configResourceBundle.geti18nDisplay( "DescriptionLabel" ) );

    descriptionText = new TextControl( paramsFieldComposite, SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.MULTI );
    descriptionText.setLayoutData( new GridData( SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 2, 3 ) );
    descriptionText.setEditable( true );

    Label defaultActionLabel = new Label( paramsFieldComposite, SWT.NONE );
    defaultActionLabel.setLayoutData( new GridData( SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false, 1, 1 ) );
    defaultActionLabel.setText( configResourceBundle.geti18nDisplay( "DefaultActionLabel" ) );

    Label defaultReportActionLabel = new Label( paramsFieldComposite, SWT.NONE );
    defaultReportActionLabel.setLayoutData( new GridData( SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false, 1, 1 ) );
    defaultReportActionLabel.setText( configResourceBundle.geti18nDisplay( "DefaultReportActionLabel" ) );

    defaultActionText = new TextControl( paramsFieldComposite, SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL );
    defaultActionText.setLayoutData( new GridData( SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false, 1, 3 ) );
    defaultActionText.setEditable( true );

    defaultReportActionText = new TextControl( paramsFieldComposite, SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL );
    defaultReportActionText.setLayoutData( new GridData( SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false, 1, 3 ) );
    defaultReportActionText.setEditable( true );
```

Here is what the GUI looks like.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The difference between the behaviour of `translationText` and `defaultActionText` is quite easy to explain.

You told both to span 3 rows. However, while the height of these three rows of `translationText` is defined by other `Widgets` (`hostnameText`, `instanceLabel`, `instanceText`), this is not the case for `defaultActionText`. There are no other widgets in these three rows (except for `defaultReportActionText`). So the height will be set to the necessary height.

You can manually increase this height by setting the `heightHint` of the `GridData`:

```
GridData data = new GridData( SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false, 1, 3 );
data.heightHint = 80;

defaultActionText.setLayoutData(data);
defaultReportActionText.setLayoutData(data);
```

The result can be seen here:

[image]

To get a more exact result for the height, you could use:

```
data.heightHint = hostnameText.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT).y
                + instanceLabel.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT).y
                + instanceText.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT).y;
```